# SQL Query : Order In month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
monthName   year    total

August     2014     10000
July       2014     20000
June       2014     56400
October    2015     20000
September  2014     23400
September  2015     10000
```

I want to order above data in month and year order like below

```
monthName  year    total

June       2014    56400
July       2014    20000
August     2014    10000
September  2014    23400
September  2015    10000
Octomber   2015    20000
```

order(Januery,Feb,March like that and 2014 then 2015 data)

I used following query as

SELECT  * FROM chartdraw GROUP BY monthName

but  i got like blow

```
monthName   year       total

August      2014       10000
July        2014       20000
June        2014       56400
October     2015       20000
September   2014       23400
```

Could you please help me with this??

Comment: is there no real date information in the source table? use a date not a month name until you present the result (or have 2 columns)

Comment: Store the dates as dates, e.g. 2014-08-01

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM chartdraw  ORDER BY DATEPART(MM, concat_ws(" ",monthname,year,01))
```

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
order by
    str_to_date(concat('1',`monthName`,`year`),'%e %M %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query and I think it is what you need exactly.

```
SELECT * FROM chartdraw order by DATEPART(mm,CAST([MONTH]+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) asc
```